# Call a function paulScripts onchange event

Tags: javascript, function, events, onchange, cognos

I would appreciate very much help with this JS function, I have inserted it in a prompt page in cognos and it works very good when the page is loaded but when the page is refreshed due to a change in one of the prompts which is the cascading source for the prompt value in the function (pGTRI5)it does not reload the Search & Select Prompt.
How do I call this function onchange event in the cascading source prompt.?